# Push value into object with the same values

Tags: jquery

can someone take a quick look at my code? im trying to push a value into an object with if the same value name as the array in my loop.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
  column_data = obj.series.data.series.data;
  drilldown_data = obj.drilldown.drilldown.series;

  $.each(column_data, function (key, val) {
    if(drilldown_data[key].id == val.name){
      drilldown_data.push(val.y);
    };
  });
  console.log(drilldown_data);
```

So after i do a console.log on drilldown_data it should look like this. With the y key inside of the object because the id is the same as the name.

```
0 : Object 
data:Array[2]
id:"test"
name:"test"
y:154
```

Comment: Yes but it adds it to the array outside of the objects....

Comment: Really not clear what you are trying to do. Broken code is not  good substitute for  proper explanation of what the code should do

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking for but looking at the required output,I cann see that you are pushing your required element in the wrong object .. take a look to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$.each(column_data, function (key, val) {
    if(drilldown_data[key].id == val.name){
      drilldown_data[key]['y']=val.y;
    };
  });
```